# angular js content assist for java models/entities in eclipse

Tags: java, json, eclipse, model, entity

Hej. Is there any plugin that w'll auto complete java models/entities and their  attributes in angularjs layer editor?
F.e. I have java model class:

```
class User {
    int id;
    String name;
  }
```

If I will type editor form in angularjs like this:

```
   <div ng-app="">
        <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-   model="User.name"></p>
        <h1>Hello {{User.name}}</h1>
    </div>
```

I Would like to eclipse give me suggestion of that model.
is it something like that out there?

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't exists a such plugin. But if you write the well AngularJS JavaScript with controller which registers in the *$scope* user JavaScritpt variable with *name* and *id* properties, [AngularJS Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse) can support this completion type.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I searching new view layer technology (SpringMVC) for Spring that will fully support Eclipse intelisense, like scala in PlayFramework (http://scala-ide.org/docs/_images/play20-scalaide20-16.png)